# Set large array of numbers to designated length per line

Tags: java, arrays

```
int size = 50;

// Generates non-duplicated random numbers
int[] values = new int[51];
int[] list = new int[size];
for( int i = 0; i < 51; i++ )
   values[i] = i;

Random rand = new Random();
int listSize = 0;
int myList = 0;

while( true )
{
   int value = rand.nextInt(51);

   if( values[ value ] == 0 )
      continue; // number already used

   list[ myList++ ] = value;
   values[ value ] = 0;

   if( myList == size || myList == 50 )
       break;
}
// Displays non-duplicated random generated numbers
for(int element : list)
   System.out.print(element + " ");
```

I would like to set a large array of numbers to a designated length per line to make all the numbers appear as though they're in a block with the left and right sides even like so:

```
> 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
> 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
> 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
> 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

How do I accomplish this using an enhanced for loop? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new line after read 10 value

```
for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
  System.out.printf(" %-2d",list[i]); //Format left justified
  if ((i+1)%10==0){
    System.out.println(); // Add a new line after 10
  }
}
```

Comment: it will not align numbers of different order of magnitude, like in the question. The first row will be shorter due to single digit numbers.

Comment: Here, maximum value is `50`, For larger value it need to increase alignment size.

Comment: @Masud Hi Masud, your code works Perfectly! All the numbers are right-aligned Perfectly! Thank you! :-) :-) :-) :-) Smiling All The Way To The Bank!

Comment: @Masud They are also left-aligned Perfectly! Thank you! :-) :-) :-) :-)